# Convertir hex string a un array de chars en C++ para enviarlo por TCP

Tags: c++, socket

Tengo una funcion que recibe un `std::string` y quiero convertir ese string a un array de char para poder enviarlo a la funcion [send de wsock32](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send)

Por ejemplo:

```
void login(std::string packetHex) {
    // el tamaño de packetHex es variable
    // por ejemplo si tengo un string asi:
    packetHex = "DAFA5F3BDEA9843DCCFD";

    // quiero convertirlo a algo asi:
    char buffer[] = {0xDA, 0xFA, 0x5F, 0x3B, 0xDE, 0xA9, 0x84, 0x3D, 0xCC, 0XFD};
}
```

Convertir el string utilizando `c_str()` no sirve porque no hace lo que busco.
Necesito convertir cada par de hex ("DA", "FA", "5F") en su respectivo valor numerico y meterlo en el buffer.

Comment: Tengo un ejemplo en Java, espero te sirva:
``` java
public static byte[] hexadecimalInTextToBinary(String texto){
        byte[]buffer=new byte[texto.length()/2];                
        for(int i=0, j=0; i<texto.length();i+=2,j++){
            String byteInText=new String(texto.substring(i,i+2));
            int decimal = Integer.parseInt(byteInText, 16);
            buffer[j]=(byte)decimal;
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias manuel, intente hacer lo mismo hace un rato pero resulto en un problema al meterlo en un char al resultado del Integer.parseInt que estas haciendo en la variable decimal.
C++ es un poquito exigente con todo y no termino de entender.